# Prove that $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x-1}} \ge 2$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

This is a simple inequality problem that I have found in a book (as part of a solution of a larger problem), however I have failed to prove it.

The only proof provided is that it is true since $(x-2)^2\ge0$ (I hope this could help you).

Can anyone please provide me with a proof or even the start of it.

Comment: Hint:  $\sqrt {x-1} >0$ at least for $x>1$ so you can cross multiply safely.

Comment: Do you mean $x\ge2$ ? But how does this prove it ?

Comment: Necessarily $x > 1$. Now, multiply by $\sqrt{x-1}$ and take the squares.

Comment: Try working backwards. Keep in mind $x>1>0$ or else the expression is not defined over the real numbers.

Comment: I meant $x>1$, else the left hand is undefined.  I didn't say it proved it, it was a hint not a complete solution.  Useful first step.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{y} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \geq 2$ where $y = x - 1 \gt 0$.

Comment: Can someone please help me with the next step.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that for every $ x > 1 $, we have
\begin{align}
       \frac{x}{\sqrt{x - 1}}
& =    \frac{x - 1}{\sqrt{x - 1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x - 1}} \\
& =    \sqrt{x - 1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x - 1}} \\
& \geq 2 \sqrt{\sqrt{x - 1} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x - 1}}} \qquad
       (\text{By the AM-GM Inequality.}) \\
& =    2.
\end{align}

Comment: How is $\frac{x - 1}{\sqrt{x - 1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x - 1}} = \sqrt{x - 1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x - 1}}$

Comment: Observe that $ \dfrac{x - 1}{\sqrt{x - 1}} = \dfrac{\left( \sqrt{x - 1} \right)^{2}}{\sqrt{x - 1}} = \sqrt{x - 1} $ for every $ x > 1 $.

Comment: @BasemFouda Note that $\frac{a}{\sqrt a}$ = $\frac{a^{2/2}}{a^{1/2}} = a^{2/2 - 1/2} = \sqrt a$.

Answer (score 4):

An elementary approach: squares are positive so $(x-2)^2\ge 0$. Dividing by $4x^2$ you obtain
$$\frac{x^2-4x+4}{4x^2}\ge 0$$
Separating the fractions, this becomes
$$\frac{1}{4}\ge\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}$$
Since both quantities are positive if $x>1$, we can take the square root and 
$$\frac{1}{2}\ge\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{x}$$
Taking reciprocals yields the result:
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x-1}}\ge 2$$

Comment: I like your solution. Frankly speaking, it is more elementary than mine as it is cast entirely in the language of ordered fields.

Answer (score 4):

A solution which uses the hint, keep in mind, everything is positive and we have $x>1$:

We start with
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{x-1}} \ge 2&\iff x\ge2{\sqrt{x-1}}\\
&\iff x^2\ge4(x-1)\\
&\iff x^2-4x+4\ge0
\end{align}
and now we see that
$$
x^2-4x+4=(x-2)^2\ge0 \text{ (hint)}
$$
and therefore we have
$$
\frac{x}{\sqrt{x-1}} \ge 2\iff(x-2)^2\ge0 
$$
which is true and therefore proves the above statement.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: differentiate $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x-1}}$, find the minimum (which is $2$ at $x=2$).

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x-1}} = \frac{t^2+1}{t} = t+\frac{1}{t} \ge 2$$
where $t = \sqrt{x-1} \ge 0$.